# Selectively displaying pages

Tags: security, http, iframe, webserver

I have a page that I am sending into an iframe. The iframe itself is being conditionally displayed based on logic in the back end. Is it possible for only the iframe to be able to display the page?

Basically I want to be able to call the page from within the iframe, but a person who accesses the URL directly will get redirected or blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `Referer` header and serve the page only if it matches the URL of the document that contains the iframe. But this will foil only a user browsing casually to the direct URL. In general the answer is no, you have no control over how the user agent is going to display the content.

If you really need to do this, generate the parent document dynamically so that it contains a URL for the iframe with an embedded random one-time token. Have the iframe content be generated by a script that checks for the validity of the one-time token before delivering the page, and deletes the token from the database at the same time. You will have to make the iframe content uncacheable and you will likely encounter side effects related to caching that cause the page to break for legitimate users from time to time.

Comment: When you say "this will foil only a user browsing casually to the direct URL" what are the other ways that page could be accessed?

Comment: You can trivially forge the `Referer` header to access the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the url for your iframe is http://example.com/myiframepage. The page that renders the iframe is http://example.com/parentpage

I am assuming your parent page already has code similar to :

```
  //in parentpage : 
  if(can_show_iframe) {
     
  }
```

You just need to go a step further and modify the code for myiframepage as follows -

```
  //in myiframepage
  if(can_show_iframe) {
     //normal processing
  }
  else {
     //return 403 error code which indicates access denied
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my question I meant if someone goes and types the URL into their browser or tries to access the page in some method besides the iframe.